# For a range of cells, first find the cells that are a certain color, then, for those cells, find if any are blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code for Excel in VBA which looks at a range of cells, in this example Range B4:B15, and first identifies which cells have a yellow fill color (interior color).  Then of the cells colored yellow determine if any of those cells are blank.

If any of the yellow cells are blank, give a message for the entire range saying "there are yellow cells that are blank".

I'm using a `For each rcell in r` loop to determine which cells are yellow colored.

How do I build a new "sub-range" with only the cells colored yellow?

```
Sub Input_Checker_test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Main")
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Dim rmain As Range
    Dim rmaincell As Range
    Set r = Range("B4:B15").Cells   
    For Each rcell In r   
        If rcell.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
            rcell = rmain
        End If
    Next rcell
    For Each rmaincell In rmain
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rmain) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Cells are empty")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Cells are full")
        End If     
    Next rmaincell           
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused because you said font, then interior.  If there is a yellow font, then there has to be a value, so I assumed you meant interior.  Since you only need one of each to meet your criteria, you don't need to create a sub-range.  You can test to see if any cells meet both criteria.

```
Sub Input_Checker_test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Main")

    Dim r As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Dim YellowCount as Integer
    Dim EmptyCount as Integer
    Set r = ws.Range("B4:B15")

    For Each rcell In r
        If rcell.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
            YellowCount = 1
            If IsEmpty(rcell) Then
                EmptyCount = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rcell

    If YellowCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are yellow cells"
    End If

    If EmptyCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are empty cells"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry - yes I meant background (interior) fill color, not font color.

Comment: Hey - thanks a bunch!  I tried out your code and it does exactly what I need it to do.  I really appreciate the help!  I didn't realize it was that simple - thanks so much!.  I can't upvote your answer because I'm brand new to Stack Overflow and have no reputation, but you solved my problem, so thanks!

Comment: @rollsboy1979 You cannot upvote, but You can mark his answer as correct :)